# How to change the configuration of dataframe to avoid lists

Tags: python

I have a dataframe df1 that I would like to transform into df2. In dataframe df1 if I take for example the first row : we have two groups of individuals of size 18 and 17. Some events are reported like Asthma amd Pneumonia. In the first group, 5 persons suffer from Asthma and  3 persons suffer from pneumonia. In the second group 6 suffer from Astham in the second group and 2 suffer from pneumonia. So I would like to change the configuration of my dataframe to get dataframe 2 to avoid the lists. I hope someone can help me.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'total of each group':[[18,17],[15,16]],'Reported events for each group':[['Asthma','Pneumonia'],['Asthma','Pneumonia','Death']],'Number of events':[[5,6,3,2],[5,6,7,2,3,4]]})

df2=pd.Dataframe(data= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'total of group 1':[18,15], 'total of group 2':[17,16],'Asthma grp1':[5,5],'Asthma grp2':[6,6],'Pneumonia grp1':[3,7],'Pneumonia grp2':[2,2],'Death grp 1':[0,3],'Death grp 2':[0,4]}
```

Here is how df 1 looks like [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/393fW.png)

Here is how df 2 looks like [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB9JX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can split a column of lists into multiple columns, the routine is simple:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "col1": [1, 2],
    "col2": [3, 4],
    "total of each group": [[18, 17], [15, 16]],
    "Reported events for each group": [
        ["Asthma", "Pneumonia"],
        ["Asthma", "Pneumonia", "Death"],
    ],
    "Number of events": [[5, 6, 3, 2], [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4]],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df3 = df1[["col1", "col2"]].copy()

df3[["total of group 1", "total of group 2"]] = df1["total of each group"]

col = ["Asthma1", "Asthma2", "Pneumonia1", "Pneumonia2", "Death1", "Death2"]
df3[col] = pd.DataFrame(df1["Number of events"].tolist(), index=df1.index).fillna(0)

df3
   col1  col2  total of group 1  total of group 2  Asthma1  Asthma2  Pneumonia1  Pneumonia2  Death1  Death2
0     1     3                18                15        5        6           3           2     0.0     0.0
1     2     4                17                16        5        6           7           2     3.0     4.0
```